# Pandas - is there an 'out the box' way to combine boolean columns representing enumerated data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a library function to make the following transformation:

```
      Enum    Column  Vals     =>       NewCol
     -----------------------   =>      --------
      True    False   False    =>        Enum
      False   True    False    =>       Column
      False   False   True     =>        Vals
```

I am sure I could write my own function to do this perfectly fine. It just feels like there should be a library function able to do this already, but I can't see one in the docs.

Comment: `df @ df.columns`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there is always exactly 1 `True` per row, you can use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) over `columns`:

```
df['NewCol'] = df.idxmax('columns')
```

[out]

```
    Enum  Column   Vals  NewCol
0   True   False  False    Enum
1  False    True  False  Column
2  False   False   True    Vals
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) to do a dot product:

```
df['NewCol'] = df.dot(df.columns)
```

Comment: oh.  this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df.join(df.stack().loc[df.stack()==True].reset_index()[['level_1']]).rename(columns={'level_1':'New_Col'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can melt and then query the data frame:

```
df['NewCol'] = (
    df.reset_index()
      .melt(id_vars=['index'])
      .query('value')
      .set_index('index')
      .drop(columns='value')
)
```